package.json not found in docker container
Project works fine when running with docker run but fails (to find package.json) when runing with docker compose up.
Following is the project structure:
├── api
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── package-lock.json
└── docker-compose.yaml

api/Dockerfile
FROM node:20.13.1-alpine3.20
LABEL authors="somebody"

RUN npm i -g nodemon

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]


docker-compose.yaml
services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: api_c
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
      - /app/node_modules

When run command docker compose up from project root get following err
...
Attaching to api_c
api_c  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
api_c  | npm ERR! syscall open
api_c  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
api_c  | npm ERR! errno -2
api_c  | npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
api_c  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
api_c  | npm ERR! enoent
api_c  |
api_c  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-05-30T12_01_13_976Z-debug-0.log
api_c exited with code 254

Running docker run -it --rm -p 4000:4000 docker-tut1-api has no issue from api dir.
What could be the reason?
System Info:
Docker: 26.1.3, build b72abbb
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Your volumes: block overwrites everything in the image's /app directory with content from the host.  If this doesn't coincidentally match exactly the filesystem layout that's in the image, you can get unexpected errors like this.
Your docker run command runs the content that's built into the image; it doesn't depend on files in the host system or a library tree in an anonymous volume.  (It doesn't have any docker run -v options.)  This is generally a good practice.
You should delete the volumes: block in your Compose file.

Here my goal is to develop with docker, this is why I've added the volumes, otherwise I've to build the image & start new container of that image every time I change something. In this circumstances, is there any way to fix the issue?

I generally use non-container tools (that is, plain node without Docker) for day-to-day development, and introduce Docker for integration testing and deployment.  You can also use Docker for external dependencies like databases while using a host-based development environment.

I also do that, but wanted to go away from that. because sometimes I need to work form home (& my team members too) in that time they need to configure their machine with everything the project uses, including lots of PHP extensions, Redis etc, & we need to do it in all sorts of OS'es as people uses different OS. Thought that Docker based development'd be a good choice for this scenario.
